# Verify Username and Password onclick in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Using a username and password text boxes, I am trying to verify that the username and password are within a table on click. Below is what I have for the button. If possible could some one review this and tell me where I am going wrong? I am new to this and could really use some advice.

Thank you for your help, It is greatly appreciated!

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub butSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles butSubmit.Click

        Dim myReader As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Dim mySqlConnection As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim mySqlCommand As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        'Establish the SqlConnection by using the configuration manager to get the connection string in our web.config file.

        mySqlConnection = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString())
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT password FROM MyUsers WHERE username = '" & Me.logon_id.Text & "'"
        mySqlCommand = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, mySqlConnection)



        Try

            mySqlConnection.Open()
            myReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

            If (myReader.HasRows) Then
                myReader.Read()
                Dim password As String = myReader("password")
                If (password = Me.user_password.Text) Then
                    'Open page with users and roles
                    Dim message As String = "Correct password"
                    Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly
                    Dim title As String = "Authenticated"
                    MsgBox(message, style, title)

                End If
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        Finally
            If Not (myReader Is Nothing) Then
                myReader.Close()
            End If

            If (mySqlConnection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open) Then
                mySqlConnection.Close()
            End If

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

==============================================================

Update:

Thank you for your post. Thank you for your advice about creating a hash of the password. It does make sense, but this is a beginner project and I don't think that was part of the requirements.

The full project is to create three tables: MyUsers, MyRole & UserRoles. The UserRole table is suppose to link a user to multiple roles. The first column will contain a reference to a user. The second column will contain a link to a role.

I am suppose to create 2 webpages. One with a table that includes all the information about the User and there roles and a second that has a username and password that is suppose to connect to the table and verify that the entered information matches whats in the table.

Below is my SQL code:

```
user_description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

user_password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO MyUsers (user_logon_id, user_full_name, user_description, user_password) VALUES 
('mcoby', 'Mary Coby', 'Class Instructor', 'password');


CREATE TABLE MyRole
(
myrole_id INT IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY,

role_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

role_description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO MyRole (role_name, role_description) VALUES ('administrator', ' Administrator of the web site');

INSERT INTO MyRole (role_name, role_description) VALUES ('user', ' User of the web site');


CREATE TABLE UserRoles
 (
    user_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MyUsers(id),

    role_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MyRole(myrole_id),
 );
```

Comment: Without more info on what the actual problem is: voted to close to be moved to [codereview.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not send/receive the clear password text from/to your database.
You should create an hash of the password and store that. When you need to check the password you reapply the hash function and checks against the database.

Also the string concatenation used in the command text it is a very bad practice. You should use Always a parameterized query to avoid sql injections and parsing problems with strings containing single quotes or decimals and dates not recognized by the database

Finally, the connection, the command, the datareader are all disposable objects and thus it is better to use the using statement

This is just an example, not tested

```
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT password FROM MyUsers WHERE username = @uname"
    Using mySqlConnection = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString())
    Using mySqlCommand = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, mySqlConnection)
        mySqlConnection.Open()
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", Me.logon_id.Text)
        result = mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
        if result Is Nothing Then
            ' User not found 
        Else
            Dim pwHash = GetHashedText(Me.user_password.Text)
            if result.ToString = pwHash Then
                'Open page with users and roles
                Dim message As String = "Correct password"
                Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly
                Dim title As String = "Authenticated"
                MsgBox(message, style, title)
            Else
                ' wrong Password 
            End If
        End If
    End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function GetHashedText(ByVal clearText As String) As String
     Dim e As New UnicodeEncoding()
     Dim sourceBytes() As Byte = e.GetBytes(clearText)
     Dim md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
     Dim hashedBytes() As Byte = md5.ComputeHash(sourceBytes)
     Return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes)
End Function
```

As you can see I have removed the SqlDataReader because I suppose that you have only one user with the username provided, and so the query returns just one row (or zero) and just the password column.
Then the password typed by the user is hashed and then checked against the hashing returned by the database. No clear password text is going along the wire and in the database side the password is crypted in such a way that neither the administrator of the remote machine could recover the original text.

Comment: I added more information to the above question. Thank you for your response. I am really new to this so any advice is always greatly appreciated!